# Object #<Object> has no method 'resetMaxAge' NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

I have strange problem, don't know what happened...
I try use connect-mongo with express-session, but it's not work. 
What i do...
I create server.js file who look like this

```
var session         = require('express-session');
var MongoStore      = require('connect-mongo')(session);

function Start() {

    var app = express();

    // Include views
    app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // Include vendor lib's
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
    app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use(favicon('public/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
    app.use(cookieParser());

    //It's a connection to DB. I wait until the connection is established and create global DB object.
    require('./db')(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            log.crit('DB connection error!');
            throw err;
        } else {

                // After connection established i use session.
                app.use(session({
                    secret: config.get('session:secret'),
                    key: config.get('session:key'),
                    cookie: {
                        path: "/",
                        httpOnly  : true,
                        maxAge    : null
                    },
                    store: new MongoStore({mongoose_connection: DB.MONGO.connection}),
                    resave: true,
                    saveUninitialized: true
                }));

                // And after i use routes.
                var routes = require('./routes')(express);
                app.use(routes);

                app.listen(port, ipaddress, function() {
                    log.notice('Node server started on ' + [ipaddress, port].join(':'));

                    cron.dbSync(function(err, cj) {
                        ...
                    });

                });
            }
        });

    };
```

For DB connection i use mongoose. And DB.MONGO included mongoose object.

Ok. I run server.js, and all worked perfectly, routing, DB access, rendering... But when i try use req.session an error

```
/node_modules/express-session/index.js:259
      req.session.resetMaxAge();
                  ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'resetMaxAge'
    at ServerResponse.end (/node_modules/express-session/index.js:259:19)
    at ServerResponse.res.redirect (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:724:8)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/routes/adminpanel/login.js:28:21)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at /Users/arthurbortnik/GitHub/GMX/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1393:13
    at model.Document.init (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:250:11)
    at completeOne (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1391:10)
```

I spent a lot of time to fix the problem and found that it occurs after I try to run res.redirect ('/ adminpanel / stocks / all');

```
          if (admin.isConfirmed && admin.checkPassword(req.body.password)) {

                req.session = {
                    adminpanel: {
                        admin   : admin,
                        auth    : true
                    }
                };

                console.log(req.session);

                res.redirect('/adminpanel/stocks/all');
            }
```

Who know what happened?

Regards, Arthur Borg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your session object when you do this:

```
req.session = {
  adminpanel: {
    admin   : admin,
    auth    : true
  }
};
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here but this is where you're losing the actual session object used by `Express`. There is a similar issue posted on github with a response from Doug Wilson.

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/82

> This is a bug in your own app--you or some module you are using is
>   overwriting req.session (i.e. doing a req.session = {} or something).
>   Overwriting req.session is not supported in this module, as
>   req.session needs to be an object with certain properties.

Comment: I do not know why did not think about it. Thank you.